# How to convert Google Maps "My Maps" to an image?

Tags: google-maps, url-shortening, screenshot

I have found this excelent tool

[My Maps -> Static Map Converter](http://imagine-it.org/google/staticmap/encodemymap.php)

Which does what I want, converting polygons, polylines and markers too.
But it has a limitation. It generates URLs so big that the static maps API returns:

> The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Large.

I know that encoded polylines can be simplified until the URL be short enough to work.
Is there any Web App which converts "My Map" to a simplified version of it using Static Maps?
Is there any other Web App which could at least take an screenshot of Google Maps and generate an image for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an improved version of the tool I linked, which solves my problem:

http://static-maps-generator.appspot.com/

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. However, the 'source code' link on your site does not work anymore...

Comment: The code has moved to https://bitbucket.org/jaderdias/static-maps-generator

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no way to generate an image from Google Maps.

The only way would be to take a screen shot using your OS or use a screen capture software.